# Spring jdbctemplate h2 dynamically switch schema

Tags: spring-boot, h2, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to have h2's in memory database switch schema's during unit testing. Almost all my data is in the default schema `PUBLIC` but to mimic how production works I need to switch to another schema `SETTINGS` for 1 query.

I have tried to switch schema's with `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setSchema("SETTINGS");`
but when I log the value of `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getSchema();` I get the default public one.
So my query fails because I get a BadSqlGrammarException because the table I try to query isn't found, which makes sense since it's in another schema.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either prefix the table with your schema (assuming the user you are using to connect to the database has sufficient privileges) like:

```
SELECT * from SETTINGS.you_other_table;
```

Or, if you can create *another* connection which specifies the schema in the connection string.

I would recommend to use the prefix as that makes it very clear you are using another schema.

Comment: Hey Niki, thx for helping, I used your solution of prepending the table with the schema for now.